# Notify answer OP when answer is deleted

Tags: feature-request, answers, notifications, deleted-answers

After hearing of 'answer deleting' going on from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39737/can-people-please-stop-editing-questions-and-removing-things) (which turned out to be a red herring), I realized that I would have no way of knowing if someone deleted my answer.

This is the feature-request for the original poster of an answer to be notified (with an inbox notification) when that answer is deleted.

It could also just be noted in the revision tab of the recent-activity page.

Comment: +1.  I've had a few of my answers deleted.  All for the same reason - my answer was a dupe of a question.  And I would like to know when this happens (I will probably upvote/favorite the question.)

Answer (score 1):

As of [June 2013](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492/152859), users can see their own deleted questions or answers by clicking "recent deleted questions" in the Questions tab of their profile, and "recent deleted answers" in the Answers tab of their own profile.

While not perfect, and limited to questions and answers posted in last 60 days, one can  visit those pages regularly and see what has been deleted.

Also, users with the [Access To Moderator Tools](//meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege can also see all their deleted posts, regardless of time of posting, by using `deleted:1` search operator. ([MSE example](//meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=deleted%3a1))

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a bit of a niche feature; answers aren't often deleted by users *other* than the OP (moderator deletion and spam/offensive flag-deletion are the only two scenarios I can think of...).

There's a request for [making deleted questions and answers visible in their authors' profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted). I think that would allow you to keep tabs on your deleted answers while also being more generally useful.

Comment: That would go a long way to solving the problem, though I still think we could get notification also.

Comment: I just had a long answer deleted by a moderator, and it surely was not spam. I assume someone figured it was off topic (which I fail to see) and flagged it. As I only posted it last night, I still noticed. If a (long) answer is deleted at any other time, I surely would like to be told about it!

Comment: (As an aside, in my above case *maybe* my answer was deleted by a moderator as I [moved it from one place to another](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123557/can-community-raise-a-duplicate-content-flag-when-an-answer-is-deleted-and-re#comment459561_123557). My comment/bounty is not about the reason for the deletion though; just saying that it might not be a niche feature after all: I like to know if posts I spent a lot of time on are deleted, especially as [I cannot list them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted).)

Comment: @Shog9 third case: mod deletion of a question, thus taking answers with it.  If the question was old, the answerer won't see it in "recent deleted posts".  Highly-upvoted answers sometimes get lost this way in question cleanups.

Answer (score -4):

If your answers are deleted, you can still see them.

[image: deleted answer]

Comment: You can see them, but you do not know that they have been deleted.

Comment: Not true, it shows up in Grey and says `deleted by [whoever deleted it]`.

Comment: No, what I mean is that you don't know that you need to revisit that page.  I think the OP is asking for a notification on the front page.

Comment: Yes, but as @Per stated, I'd have to revisit that page.  I do visit my Q&A occasionally to see if they need updating, but the answer would disappear from my answer list, so I would never know to go there.