# Can Community ♦ raise a duplicate content flag when an answer is deleted and re-posted as a new answer?

Tags: feature-request, answers, deleted-answers, automatic-flags

I haven't seen this behavior out in the wild much, but it happened again recently and I was wondering if a flag could be automatically raised when this happens:

- User posts answer
- Answer is down voted
- User deletes answer
- User posts *exact* same text as a new answer
- User effectively ditched down votes

  - Got down voted again? Wash, rinse and repeat.
  - Profit (perhaps after modifying the post, which is what you should have done to begin with)

I feel that this should raise a duplicate content flag, with slightly stronger wording. Would this be possible to implement? Or, perhaps, don't let users post new answers if they have a deleted answer to a question. Rather, force them to edit and restore the deleted answer instead, unless locked by a moderator.

I do have a link, but I don't want a lot of people to descend on it and create an even bigger disruption. It happened exactly as I described.

Comment: Can we just outright reject reposted duplicate answers altogether, regardless of whether the original was deleted or not?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn That has come up before, but I can't find a consensus. I had suggested hashing posts to detect this, but I can't remember _where_ now, and I can't find it. Shame on me for just writing a comment :)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn However, presumably posts are _already_ hashed, they would have to be in order for the duplicate content checking bot to work. Given that, I'm sure there's a reason they aren't blocked. I'm not saying it's a _good_ reason, but I think one must exist. Too expensive of a check on submission, perhaps?

Comment: Of course, such checks could be defeated rather easily by simply changing a word or two. Some kind of similarity algorithm would be more robust, but also more expensive.

Comment: @hammar In this (and previous cases) the text was identical. I'd really be interested in seeing Community ♦ churn these up. Ignoring common words might help pick up more, but baby steps :)

Comment: @hammar such a similarity algorithm could also very easily block legitimately improved answers being posted after the owner deletes the original. Isn't this exactly what mods are for? I can't imagine this is so amazingly common we need to automatically block it.

Comment: @Ben: well, the request is to *flag* the post, not block it. But I'm not sure a content check is needed at all - wanna dig into this a bit, and see what the false-positive rate of just flagging all answers posted by a user with an existing, deleted answer would be.

Comment: *Maybe* moderators also need better tools to see the old post? Just a thought: I might have one of my answers deleted by a moderator, when I moved it from one question to a more generic question, within an hour after posting it. I first copied to [the new place](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13887960), then edited and deleted [the old](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13887545). I'm not sure, but *maybe* this raised a flag, and when that was handled 3 hours later the moderator did not realize that I moved it to a better place. No voting was involved. @BoltClock, what's wrong with moving an answer?

Comment: @Arjan: I didn't say not to move an answer. I said we shouldn't let duplicate answers exist.

Comment: Okay, @BoltClock, your (10 times upvoted) *reject reposted duplicate answers altogether, regardless of whether the original was deleted or not?* made me feel otherwise. Isn't reposting the only way a mortal user can move an answer?